# textcolor() and textbackground() in C

Tags: c, dos, turbo-c, text-coloring, retro-computing

I am having a project using C (the compiler I think I am using is [Turbo C++ 3.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C%2B%2B)). I used some `textcolor()` and `textbackground()` functions to color some text. When I run it the first time, the console is in its normal colors—white text on black background.

[image: The colors of the console is in their normal/default state when I run it the first time.]

However, when I run the code for the second time and so on, the background color becomes blue.

[image: When I run the code for the second time and so on, the background color becomes blue.]

I used the following code for the above program (the only formatted text using `cprintf()` were the text in magenta and blue backgrounds):

```
...
gotoxy(10, 19);
textcolor(LIGHTCYAN);
textbackground(MAGENTA);
cprintf(" A "); printf(" ");
cprintf(" F "); printf(" ");
cprintf(" G "); printf(" ");
cprintf(" K "); printf(" ");
cprintf(" Z "); printf(" ");
cprintf(" E "); printf(" ");
cprintf(" I "); printf(" ");
...
```

I suspect this is because of the compiler I am using but I am still not sure. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: reset colours to their defaults after each run

Comment: It worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you are done drawing the letters you want to have MAGENTA background you should reset the background color back to BLACK:

```
textbackground(BLACK);
```